# switch statement not working, only first case triggers actions

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

I'm new to writing switch statements after learning about it yesterday.

For some reason, this isn't working.

```
checkCase(2);
checkCase(1);
checkCase(0);
function checkCase(priorityType){
switch(priorityType){
     case 2:
         print(priorityType);
         break;             
        case 1:
        print(priorityType);
            break;          
        case 0:
        print(priorityType);
        break;
     }
}
```

The 'alert(2)' is triggered, 1 and 0 are not. 
I've reversed the case 2: with case 1: and run the code again and 2 is once again triggered, 1 is not. 
I've also tried adding break; and continue; to the cases, but still nothing.

Why is that? what have I done wrong?
----------------------EDIT---------------------------
Lots of responses saying that I need to add 'break;' which I've now done to each line. 
Still no output. I've also changed 'alert' to 'print'. No difference.

-------------edit2-----------------------
my bad, the 'break' is working now. not sure what was going on when I checked last. Maybe needed to restart ff.

Comment: [Here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/patrick_dw/SBLwn/) with your code except that I changed it back to `alert()`. With the breaks, you'll see 3 alerts.

Comment: Firefox usually caches pages and data so if you update your code you may have to clear cache or restart the browser to see the changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two problems: Debugging using `alert` is problematic and you need `break` statements.

Try adding `break`s and using `print` in the [square free shell](http://squarefree.com/shell/shell.html), and I think you'll see the proper result.

```
checkCase(2);
checkCase(1);
checkCase(0);
function checkCase(priorityType){
switch(priorityType){
     case 2:
         print(priorityType);               break;
        case 1:
        print(priorityType);            break;
        case 0:
        print(priorityType);   break;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You must `break;` after each case.

```
function checkCase(priorityType){
    switch(priorityType){
        case 2:
             alert(priorityType);
        break;         

        case 1:
            alert(priorityType);    
        break;        

        case 0:
            alert(priorityType);
        break;

        //my two cents
        default:
            alert("No intended code for"+priorityType);
     }
}

checkCase(2);
checkCase(1);
checkCase(0);
```

Answer (score 1):

Because there are no break statements, once a matched case is found, it and the subsequent cases will fire.

So when you do:

```
checkCase(2);
```

You'll get:

```
alert(2);
alert(2);
alert(2);
```

When you do:

```
checkCase(1);
```

You'll get:

```
alert(1);
alert(1);
```

When you do:

```
checkCase(0);
```

You'll get:

```
alert(0);
```

If you were hoping to get:

```
alert(2);
alert(1);
alert(0);
```

You'd need to change your switch to include `break;` statements.

```
function checkCase(priorityType){ 
   switch(priorityType){
     case 2:
         alert(priorityType);
         break;           
     case 1:
        alert(priorityType);       
        break;     
     case 0:
        alert(priorityType);
        break;
     }
}
```